# Can I change position of geometry crop marks showing the same crop area?

Tags: geometry, crop

I wonder if I can left more space between the `geometry` crop marks and the text itself. I don't want to change the cropped area.

MWE demonstrates obvious behaviour of `geometry` crop marks.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ paperheight  =297mm,paperwidth   =210mm, 
             layoutheight =197mm,layoutwidth  =130mm,
             layoutvoffset= 50mm,layouthoffset= 40mm,
             margin=0pt, includeheadfoot,
             showcrop=true]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\chapter{In the Beginning}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro \cropmarkgap adjustable from 0 to 20 (mm).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ paperheight  =297mm,paperwidth   =210mm, 
             layoutheight =197mm,layoutwidth  =130mm,
             layoutvoffset= 50mm,layouthoffset= 40mm,
             margin=0pt, includeheadfoot,
             showcrop=true]{geometry}

\def\cropmarkgap{10}% mm

\makeatletter
\def\Gm@cropmark(#1,#2,#3,#4){% #1 = x direction, #2 = y direction, #3 & #4 no longet used
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \setlength\unitlength{1truemm}%
    \linethickness{0.25pt}%
    \put(\the\numexpr #1*\cropmarkgap\relax,0){\line(#1,0){\the\numexpr 20-\cropmarkgap}}%
    \put(0,\the\numexpr #2*\cropmarkgap\relax){\line(0,#2){\the\numexpr 20-\cropmarkgap}}%
  \end{picture}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{In the Beginning}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I decided to change \Gm@cropmark and leave \Gm@pageframes as is.  Now the gap is adjustable and the length = 20mm - gap.

Comment: This is very useful answer. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `20` to whatever you need:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[paperheight =197mm,paperwidth  =130mm,
margin=0pt, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}
\thinlines\unitlength1pt
\newcommand*\CROPmarkLT{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-20,0){\line(-1,0){50}}\put(0,20){\line(0,1){50}}
    \end{picture}}
\newcommand*\CROPmarkRT{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(20,0){\line(1,0){50}}\put(0,20){\line(0,1){50}}
    \end{picture}}
\newcommand*\CROPmarkLB{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-20,0){\line(-1,0){50}}\put(0,-20){\line(0,-1){50}}
    \end{picture}}
\newcommand*\CROPmarkRB{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(20,0){\line(1,0){50}}\put(0,-20){\line(0,-1){50}}
    \end{picture}}
\newcommand*\CROPinfo{\jobname\ \today}
\cropdef[\CROPinfo]\CROPmarkLT\CROPmarkRT\CROPmarkLB\CROPmarkRB{CROP}
\crop[CROP]
\begin{document}
    \chapter{In the Beginning}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is usefull as well, but it uses different package. The question regards `geometry` crop marks.